# How to change the name of a value in R

Tags: r

I misspelled a name and am wanting to change it in R rather than in my .csv file.
The dataframe (named "data_scores") looks as follows:

```
 Species  Stn_142   Stn_175   Stn_219 
1 Krill eggs 3.319314 0.0000000 0.0000000
2 Polychaete 0.000000 2.5899496 2.5774918
3 Gastropoda 1.079181 4.0773679 4.1901355
4   Nauplius 1.913814 3.6901961 2.2405492
5 Fish larva 0.000000 0.0000000 0.4771213
6  Other egg 1.041393 0.0000000 1.0413927
7 Trocophore 0.000000 0.7781512 0.0000000
```

I want to change "Trocophore" to "Trochophore".

I have looked online and tried multiple ways though they return errors. I have looked up what these errors mean and still don't understand:

- df["data_scores"][df["data_scores"] == "Trocophore"] <- "Trochophore"
  Error in `*tmp*`["data_scores"] :
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
- mutate(Species = recode(Species, Trocophore = "Trocophore" ))
- df[df=="Trocophore"] <- "Trochophore"
  Error in df == "Trocophore" :
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

I am new to R and would appreciate any help:) Thank you!

Comment: Try `sub("Trocophore", "Trochophore", data_scores$Species)`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is related to the incorrect use of data frame subsetting. You can achieve what you need using the dplyr package, which is a popular package for data manipulation in R.

```
library(dplyr)

data_scores <- data_scores %>%
  mutate(Species = ifelse(Species == "Trocophore", "Trochophore", Species))
```

Make sure you have the dplyr package installed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In base R the logic goes something like this:

```r
data_scores <- read.table(text = 
"Species  Stn_142   Stn_175   Stn_219 
1 'Krill eggs' 3.319314 0.0000000 0.0000000
2 'Polychaete' 0.000000 2.5899496 2.5774918
3 'Gastropoda' 1.079181 4.0773679 4.1901355
4   'Nauplius' 1.913814 3.6901961 2.2405492
5 'Fish larva' 0.000000 0.0000000 0.4771213
6  'Other egg' 1.041393 0.0000000 1.0413927
7 'Trocophore' 0.000000 0.7781512 0.0000000")

# you can access a column as a vector:
data_scores$Species
#> [1] "Krill eggs" "Polychaete" "Gastropoda" "Nauplius"   "Fish larva"
#> [6] "Other egg"  "Trocophore"

# and you can create a boolean vector that indicates if some condition is   
# TRUE or FALSE:
data_scores$Species == "Trocophore"
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# which in turn can be used with the column for indexing:
data_scores$Species[data_scores$Species == "Trocophore"]
#> [1] "Trocophore"

# and then you can add an assignment to the mix:
data_scores$Species[data_scores$Species == "Trocophore"] <- "Trochophore"

# result:
data_scores
#>       Species  Stn_142   Stn_175   Stn_219
#> 1  Krill eggs 3.319314 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 2  Polychaete 0.000000 2.5899496 2.5774918
#> 3  Gastropoda 1.079181 4.0773679 4.1901355
#> 4    Nauplius 1.913814 3.6901961 2.2405492
#> 5  Fish larva 0.000000 0.0000000 0.4771213
#> 6   Other egg 1.041393 0.0000000 1.0413927
#> 7 Trochophore 0.000000 0.7781512 0.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can use case_when to do it too.

```
library(dplyr)

data_scores  <- data_scores %>%
  mutate(
    Species = case_when(
      Species == "Trocophore" ~ "Trochophore",
      TRUE ~ Species
))
```